# Is there a term used to describe both an equation and inequality?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

Is there a term used to describe both an equation and inequality? 
The closest thing I can think of is "relation".

Comment: I'd use "relation" too.

Comment: How about inequation? :-).

Comment: It depends on context, but to the extent these are not tautologies, they are often constraints.

Comment: For many authors "inequalities" include "equalities", just like noncommutative rings include commutative rings (here 'non' means 'not necessarily').

Comment: Note that an equality is just two inequalities in opposite directions.

Comment: I would say "condition," a la the sort of thing you get from a sentence of logic with a constraint on its truth value; but I'd probably have to explain myself.

Comment: I'm with BD on "inequality" as being a natural choice.

Comment: Related question I have: What about general relations with the same gravitas as *identities*? For instance, $\sin\theta \le 1$ (for real $\theta$). I've toyed with the term "comparity". In light of @BillDubuque's comment, perhaps "nonidentity" would be more appropriate.